# What is possible to extract from Landau-Ginsburg theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition

Landau-Ginsburg theory efficiently describe physics in vicinity of critical point and predict approximate critical exponents in 3d through $4-\varepsilon$ expansion.

But as I understand, in continuous limit LG theory in principle also describe physics not only in vicinity of critical point.

**Is it possible to predict something about system besides critical exponents?**

Comment: Can your provide an example?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov, Example of what? $4-\varepsilon$ expansion? Example is calculation of critical indices of Ising 3.

Comment: A concrete example of GL using. For Ising, I assume that "Introduction to the FRG" is enough

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov,   Also famous examples are O(N)  models. For example famous XY model (O(2)). This theories describe continuous limit of systems with such symmetries on microscopic level.

Comment: My question: is it possible to extract something else besides critical exponents.

Comment: Are you sure about XY model?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov, Of course. It describe phase transition in He3, He4, read something about Statistical field theory

Comment: *predict true critical exponents in 3d through 4−ε expansion* Do you have a source for this statement, as I find it very unlikely?  Sure, you can obtain approximate values by computing a few orders and setting $\epsilon=1$, but getting exact values from this approach seems completely hopeless (even if the radius of convergence of the expansion was large enough to allow you to do that).

Comment: @YvanVelenik, yes, I agree with you. I edited question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it seems there are some disagreements in both the comments and other answers about what actually constitutes Landau-Ginsburg theory. But based on what you have said in the comments, it seems that you are asking about using statistical or quantum field theory to describe the scaling limit of a system near a critical point. If this is your question, the answer is **yes, there are many other observables besides critical exponents one can calculate**.

Maybe the "textbook" examples are so-called "amplitude ratios." For example, if one considers how the specific heat diverges as one approaches the critical point from above or below, one can write
$$
C = A^{\pm} |t|^{-\alpha}, \qquad t \equiv T - T_c \rightarrow \pm 0.
$$
Then even though the $A^{\pm}$ are both non-universal, the ratio $A^+/A^-$ of the amplitudes turns out to be universal and can be calculated, say using the $\epsilon$ or $1/N$ expansions. One may define similar amplitude ratios for the susceptibility, spontaneous magnetization, etc. There are other ratios of particular quantities which turn out to be universal and calculable in perturbative field theory, see Chapter 29 in Jean Zinn-Justin's textbook *Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena*.

I gave the above example because it's the first obvious example, but in principle one expects an infinite number of "universal" quantities you could consider calculating. For example, one can consider the scaling dimensions of all local primary operators in a given CFT like the Ising model (assuming there are an infinite number of primaries, which is presumably always the case in $d>2$). Another example: place the theory in a finite volume of some sort. You will now find that the correlation length $\xi$ is finite, but the ratio $\xi/L$ (where L is some length scale parametrizing the size of the system) is universal. But I can do this for whatever shape I want, so there are an infinite number of such quantities $\xi/L$ I could try calculating. (Very interestingly, for a particular choice one actually has $\xi/L$ equal to the scaling dimension of the lowest primary of the CFT.) The bulk of my own PhD thesis consisted of my calculating new universal quantities for quantum ($T = 0$) phase transitions using $\epsilon$ or $1/N$ techniques, partially to compare with numerical calculations in microscopic lattice models.

Comment: Thank you! You cover some issues, that I am interested in. But what about "non-universal" quantities? Is it possible to extract such information from LG theory?

Comment: I would basically define "non-universal quantities" to be precisely those quantities which disagree between theories which are in the same universality class. That is, if one places $\phi^4$ theory on the lattice and an Ising model on the same lattice, the universal quantities are those which agree between the two theories, and the non-universal ones are those which disagree.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand your question correctly.

You can check Chapter 2 (paragraphs 2.2 & 2.3, where authors uses GL theory for Ising model) of "Introduction to the Functional Renormalization Group" by Kopietz. In my opinion, GL theory is nothing more than introducing an auxiliary field to simplify description of phase transition and to understand how it appears.

For instance, you can consider 4-fermion attractive interaction, find that there is the Cooper instability in theory. Then it is convenient to introduce auxialiary field $\Delta$ by (formally exact) Hubbard-Stratatnovich transformation and consider effective action for new theory. With several approximations and assumptions, you can expand the obtained effective action in terms of $\Delta$ and find critical exponents for superconductor.

So, for superconductor you can extract effective action & critical exponents.

In general, you always can find effective action in terms of auxiliary field and find MF value of order parameter (besides critical exponents, in my opinion).

Roughly speaking, I understand GL theory as usual mean-field approach and therefore I am not sure that it deals with $4-\epsilon$ expansion.

I am not sure about XY model. In XY model the phase transition is caused by non-trivial solutions of EOM. You start from $\mathcal{Z}_{XY}$, then find that can be approximated in terms of dual theory. Is it GL approach in your opinion?